# 3D rectangle coordinates knowing 2 coordinates , and the elevation of the 2 others

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I have this simple 3D geometry problem that I need to solve in order to go to the next step with a python script.
Please check the attached image.
here is what I know :

- A, B coordinates (X,Y, Z)
- A and B always have the same Z
- The distance AB therefore can be calculated
- The alpha angle which the segments BD and AC make with the plane (P1)
- The elevation of C and D( Z coordinates of C and D, both of them always have the same Z)
- ABCD is a rectangle
  I want to make an excel sheet in which I'll have A, B coords the angle alpha and the elevation of C and D as input and the output will be the X, Y, Z coords of C and D
  PS: Keep in mind that the rectangle can be in any orientation in 3D space there is no specific reference point.
  I m not really good at math I m a programmer so please use some value here are some raw data:
  A coords = 0,0,0 (x,y,z)
  B coords = 3,3,0
  C Z coord = 5
  D Z coord = 5
  Alpha = 36°

Check this image.

[image: img]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Two solutions are possible.

Comment: it's okay i want both of them

Answer (score 1):

As $AC$ is perpendicular to $AB$ we get a first equation:
$$
(x_C-x_A)(x_B-x_A)+(y_C-y_A)(y_B-y_A)=0.
$$
From $\tan\alpha=CH/AH$ (where $H$ is the projection of $C$ on plane $z=z_A$) we obtain a second equation:
$$
(x_C-x_A)^2+(y_C-y_A)^2=(z_C-z_A)^2\cot^2\alpha.
$$
It is not difficult to solve this system of equations for the unknowns $(x_C-x_A)$ and $(y_C-y_A)$. Apply the same technique to find $(x_D-x_B)$ and $(y_D-y_B)$.